# How can I get the value of Validation Message from form in ASP.Net MVC, using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hy,

In my ASP.NET MVC application in the aspx page I set

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

to enable client validation on my form. So, for my input I have this code to declare the texbox for email and it's validation

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)%>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)%>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true)%>
```

In the model I declare the email property like:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required email")]
 [DisplayName("Email *")]
 [RegularExpression("^[a-z0-9+\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9+\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid email.")]
 public string Email { get; set; }
```

The question is, how can I get (using client script) the value of the error message when it's displayed on the page?

So when I press some button I can see if the form is valid or not and after that I can display a loading gif.

Thanks a lot.

Jeff

**Update**

HTML source code:

```
<tr>
   <td class="editor-field">
      <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="editor-field-validation">
     <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Email_validationMessage"></span>
     <div class="validation-summary-valid" id="validationSummary"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML source code which the browser will recieve and how about your javascript code to getting the validation message?

Comment: you cannot depend on the validation on the cleint side you need to have a separate client side validation cos your client can fake the request easily using different tools like Fiddler

Comment: @reporter, I'ved tried geting the value of 'Email_validationMessage' but all that I can get is 'undefined'.. so that's the point of my question, How can I get the validation message

Comment: Can't get wat you are trying to say please be more clear. How did u try to get the value of Email_validationMessage ?

Comment: is the point to show the validation text for client validation or you want to show the loading gif when buttons is pressed?

Comment: @Dejan.S The point is that I need to test if the form is valid or not, if it's valid I show the loading gif, if not, I hide it. I was thinking to get the validation message, if it's null then the form is valid, if it has some value then the form is invalid.

Comment: @AmGates I get the value of 'Email_validationMessage' like: document.getElementById('Email_validationMessage').value

Comment: you dont need to make a check i think. you could do a jquery.submit() on the button or the form id, what i think is that the submit wont go through if the form is not valid, if it is valid it will go on with submiting and you could show the gif. need more help or you got it from here?

Comment: Can u paste the javascript part of the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of error message (text) will probably displayed in div or span. Simply check what will be the id of that field (for example with FireBug). And then you will be able to get the value of that when you'll need it.

Because I understand that you are calling validation manualy in JavaScript, yes?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, i'ved installed firebug, and I checked the id of the validation message and when it's set, I get the span value like this $("span#Email_validationMessage").html() and when is '' the loading can show.